# Why does using to_char function give me error results when field is null?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have col Shipped_EXpired_Date is date datatype but there is a null field and I want to select it using

```
To_char (Shipped_EXpired_Date,YYYYMMDDHH24MISS)
```

I have ora error due to conversion null data

I have tried these:

1. `NVL2(Shipped_EXpired_Date,TO_CHAR(x ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),'19900101')  Shipped_EXpired_Date`
2. `TO_CHAR(NVL(Shipped_EXpired_Date,'1990-01-01') ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  Shipped_EXpired_Date`

By logic solution 2 is right but also wrong.

Comment: Post your error, and make sure none of your column entries are empty. If so, add an if staement to handle that case.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: The second argument needs to be surrounded by single quotes.  That may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you are mixing and matching data types, which means some implicit conversions may take place, and thus your NLS settings at session level could make (or break) your solution.

Keep everything to DATE until the final conversion to a string and you'll be fine.

```
SQL> create table t ( Shipped_EXpired_Date date );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values (null);

1 row created.

SQL> select NVL2(Shipped_EXpired_Date,TO_CHAR(Shipped_EXpired_Date ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),'19900101')  Shipped_EXpired_Date from t;

SHIPPED_EXPIRE
--------------
19900101

SQL> select TO_CHAR(NVL(Shipped_EXpired_Date,'1990-01-01') ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  Shipped_EXpired_Date from t;
select TO_CHAR(NVL(Shipped_EXpired_Date,'1990-01-01') ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  Shipped_EXpired_Date from t
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL> select TO_CHAR(NVL(Shipped_EXpired_Date,date '1990-01-01') ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')  Shipped_EXpired_Date from t;

SHIPPED_EXPIRE
--------------
19900101000000
```